# GDAL (Or Any Open Source GIS SDKS) | Read ESRI Geometric Network

Tags: gdal, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, geometric-network

I am looking at some legacy ArcObjects code that reads & parses a geometric network.  I no longer have access to ESRI license(s) at any level - so legacy code needs to be reworked since ArcObjects are off the table...

Are there any open source libraries that can read geometric networks?  Don't really care what language (python, c#, java,..etc).  My specific needs are:

- Get Edge Ids of items (i.e. edges) particpating in geometric network
- Correlate edge to feature in source feature class